# Where is fopen reading from?

Tags: ios, c, file, fopen

I have a program that uses a C library and it needs to load a file without a path, I mean like `fopen("myfile.txt", "rb");`. I know that it would be a good idea to change this library code to have a full path, but I can't for some reasons.

I tried to store `myfile.txt` on the bundle, in the Library directory, at the `Application Path`, and also in `Documents` but it is always returning `NULL`. Where is it reading from?

Comment: Without a path it will read from the "current directory".

Comment: Why can't you specify a full path to `fopen`?

Comment: You can use `strace` or `ltrace` to get the full path.

Comment: @rmaddy I know that it should be reading from the current directory, that should be the Application directory, but I already stored a file there and it wasn't open. Also I can't specify the full path because I can't change the library source code and the filename is hardcoded

Comment: You can't make any assumptions about the current working directory - it can vary depending on how the app is launched.

Comment: How can I use strace or ltrace on iOS?

Comment: what library is it? can you open an issue with them?

Comment: Print the current working directory. However, as Paul R. noted, the current working directory can change depending on how the program is started. You don't need to hard code the path, you can build it up from environment variables.

Comment: @DanielA.White: No, it is not a possible duplicate. There, the issue seems to be the format in which the string was passed to the function.

Comment: The library is an internal library and for internal reason I cant change the source code. When I print the working directory it says "/", that on iOS it means (I think) the application directory, but even if I left the file on the app directory it cant find the file (returning null)

Comment: What is this file to the library? How do you know there is no way for you to affect the name of the file that it will open? If there is no way for you to affect the name, please let us know what the name of the library is so future programmers will know to avoid using it.

Comment: `/` is not the "application directory", it's the root directory - but even knowing this, you shouldn't assume that this will always be the current working directory when you are launched. You need to fix the real underlying problem, not use guesswork and duck tape to "fix" this problem.